# How can I express this sentence in a better way? this sentence: "I’d be grateful for a piece of advice from a more experienced person."

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I'd like to say thank you more formally on the Internet forum. I also want to express that this particular question is addressed to a someone with much more experience. Can I say something like this?

"I’d be grateful for a piece of advice from a more experienced person."

Can I express this in other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that sentence is just fine, at least grammatically. You can also say these:

> I'd be grateful for some advice from a more experienced person.
>   I'd be grateful for advice from a more experienced person.
>   I'd be grateful for a bit of advice from a more experienced person.
>   I'd be grateful for a little advice from a more experienced person.

*Advice* by itself is an uncountable noun, so what you have in your title is wrong: you can't say *an advice*. As you have it in your actual post, you need to say *a [something] of advice* or *a little advice* if you use the indefinite article.

All that said, none of these are a way of thanking someone for advice already given, they are a way of asking for advice. So, if you want to say thank you for some advice already given, you need to say that you *are* grateful, not that you *would be* grateful. Also, you would say that you are grateful for some specific piece or pieces of advice. Something like this:

> I'm grateful for the advice I've been given by the people on this forum.

Finally, *I'd like to say thank you more formally way on the Internet forum* is wrong. It needs to be either of these:

> I'd like to say thank you more formally on the internet forum.
>   I'd like to say thank you in a more formal way on the internet forum.

*Formally* is the adverb form of *formal.* In the first sentence, *formally* modifies the verb *say.* In the second sentence, *formal* modifies the noun *way*.

Comment: That one with "more formally" and "way" was just a copy-paste mistake. What about "a piece of advice " in this sentence: "I’d be grateful for a piece of advice from a more experienced person."? Doesn't sound natural? Should I replace it with your suggestions (a little of/ a bit of)? I can't see a difference between these three suggestions. Does "a piece of advice" sound old-fashioned?

Comment: @Codewife_101 No, your sentence is fine. You asked if you could express it in other ways, and I was just giving you some examples of how to do that. I didn't mean to imply that you should replace the original. And, by the way, when using *little* with an uncountable noun, we don't use *of*. So *a little advice*, not *a little of advice*. But, once we make the noun countable, we use *little of*. So, *I drank a little water*, but *I drank a little of the water in the glass.*

Answer (score 1):

> from a more experienced person

could become

> from a person with more experience

or

> from someone with more experience

All of those options are grammatical. The last, IMO, is the most "natural". But it is a matter of opinion.

There, **with** could be paraphrased as *having* or *possessing*.